# Saber si una letra esta en una palabra c++

Tags: c++

tengo un arreglo a[]={'h','o,'l',a'};

quiero saber como hacer para poder leer una letra con un cin>>, y que me diga si esa letra es parte del arreglo hola, gracias por su ayuda.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int n=1;
    int i=0;
    char letra;
    char palabra[]={'h','o','l','a'};

    do{
    cout<<"Digite una palabra"<<endl;
    cin>>letra;
    for(int x=0; x<palabra[]; i++ ){
    if(letra==palabra[i]){
        cout<<"Correcto"<<endl;
    }else{
        cout<<"Equivocado"<<endl;
    }
        }while(n!=0);
    i++;
    }
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que compartas el código/investigación que llevas cómo avance, de lo contrario podría parecer que lo que quieres es que te resuelvan tu tarea, lo cual no es bien visto en el sitio. Te recomiendo leer el último párrafo de [este link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) de la comunidad.

Comment: no es mi tarea, de hecho estoy aprendiendo a programar, y estoy resolviendo ejercicios que me encuentro en internet, y vi ese ejercicio y nada mas, pero si te molesta lo borro

Comment: No deberías de jamás borrar tu pregunta solo si le molesta a alguien. El mensaje va dirigido a la gente que busca que le hagan la tarea, pero si tu no eres así es todo un placer ayudarte (hay mucha gente que abusa del sitio y sus usuarios), de igual manera consider o de mucha ayuda que compartas lo que llevas, aunque sea poco (para esto edita tu pregunta). Te recomiendo  de la manera más respetuosa posible que leas [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Te ayudo un poco, te sugiero que recorras tu arreglo (puede ser con un ciclo `for`) y en cada iteración revises si se tiene una coincidencia con la letra que obtuviste del usuario.

Answer (score 0):

Pues lo que debes hacer crear primeramente una variable donde reciba un carácter, luego crea un bucle for y recorre cada dato de tu arreglo y finalmente pon tus sentencias `if` donde puedas ver si tu letra ingresada por teclado es igual a alguna letra dentro del arreglo:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
  char a[4] = {
    'h',
    'o',
    'l',
    'a'
  };
  char letra;
  bool existe = false;
  cin >> letra;
  for (int i = 0; i < 4 /*->(en esta parte es la cantidad de caracteres)*/ ; i++) {
    if (a[i] == letra) {
      existe = true;
    }
  }
  if (existe) {
    cout << "La letra existe dentro del arreglo" << endl;
  } else {
    cout << "La letra no existe dentro del arreglo" << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias, compañero, me ayudo mucho!